# python optimal way to write dict into html table

Tags: python, html, list, dictionary

I m a python beginner and I'm trying to learn how to do this the optimal way. 
I have a list composed by few dicts. I have a fuction to search a value, and return the whole dict if found. # I m not so proud of my else as well...
It will then print a table with containing a column with the keys and one with the values.

```
car1 = {'brand':'skoda','model':'fabia','color':'blue'}
car2 = {'brand':'opel','model':'corsa','color':'red'}
car3 = {'brand':'Audi','model':'a3','color':'black'}
list = [car1,car2,car3]


def getProp(value,carList):
    for elements in carList:
        for i in elements.itervalues():
            if value.lower() == i.lower():
                return elements
            else:
                # empty dict 
                return elements.fromkeys(elements,'')

def printTable(dic):
    html = '<table border=1> < th> CAR </th> <th>PROPERTIES </th>'

    for i in dic.iterkeys():
        html+='<tr> <td> %s </td> <td> %s </td> </tr>' %(i,dic[i])

    html+='</table>'
    print html 

properties = getProp('Opel',list)
print properties
printTable(properties)
```

Comment: I have one improvement  for your question: please correct the indent of your code

Comment: And what exactly is your question? Is your question the title or the content of your question? What's not working or more specifically what is it that you want us to fix?

Comment: Put some ```print``` statements/functions in the ```for i in elements.itervalues():``` loop suite to see what is happening.

Comment: I m looking for some suggestions improvements to solve the problem.
write a function which, for a given brand, model or colour, returns all the
properties of the car. Output the result as an html table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to be looking for code suggestions here are mine:

1) Don't define your data structure across multiple variables, use a single compound data structure;

2) Don't write the raw HTML yourself, use one of the many Python HTML helper modules.

Combining my suggestions above, I come up with the following rework (warning, Python3 instead of Python2 like your original):

```
from webhelpers2.html import HTML

cars = {
    'car1': {'brand': 'skoda', 'model': 'fabia', 'color': 'blue'},
    'car2': {'brand': 'opel', 'model': 'corsa', 'color': 'red'},
    'car3': {'brand': 'Audi', 'model': 'a3', 'color': 'black'}
    }

def getProp(carValue, carList):

    for car, dic in carList.items():

        for value in dic.values():

            if carValue.lower() == value.lower():
                return dic

    # else return empty dict
    return {}.fromkeys(carList['car1'], '')

def printTable(dic):

    print(HTML.tag('html',
        HTML.tag('body',
            HTML.tag('table',
                HTML.tag('tr',
                    HTML.tag('th', 'CAR'), HTML.tag('th', 'PROPERTIES')
                    ),
                *[HTML.tag('tr',
                    HTML.tag('td', key), HTML.tag('td', value)
                    ) for key, value in dic.items()]
                )
            )
        )
    )

properties = getProp('Opel', cars)
print(properties)
printTable(properties)
```

Other folks will obviously have additional/different suggestions.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your suggestion, I did not know about this way of writting html code. Do you have a suggestion as well to do something better if the search value is not found? else statement in getProp